# Query between two dates + another column is not working in Hibernate 5

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am able to fetch records using

```
`Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(GenerateInvoiceBean.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("dealerId", dealerId)).add(Restrictions.between("billDate", frDate, tDate));
List<GenerateInvoiceBean> gib = crit.list();
            return gib;`
```

As createCriteria is deprecated in Hibernate 5.1.16, I am trying to use

```
`CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<GenerateInvoiceBean> query = builder.createQuery(GenerateInvoiceBean.class);

            Root<GenerateInvoiceBean> root = query.from(GenerateInvoiceBean.class);
            query.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("dealerId"), dealerId)).where(builder.between(root.get("billDate"), frDate, tDate))
            .orderBy(builder.asc(root.get("billNo")));

            List<GenerateInvoiceBean> gib = session.createQuery(query).getResultList();
            return gib;`
```

which is not working.
Any solution or suggestion would be great! Thanks

Comment: why are you calling `where` multiple times? It will use the last one only! Pass multiple clauses in to the sole call to `where`. Clearly "is not working" ought to have lead you to look at the LOG for the JPA provider and decide WHAT "is not working", and then tell people that

Comment: Yes you are right @DN1 Sir, only the last `where` part is working. Can you help me resolving it? `Hibernate: select * from Invoice generatein0_ where generatein0_.bill_date between ? and ? order by generatein0_.bill_no asc` Hibernate is resolved to this query on log.

Comment: I already did, above. `where` can take in MULTIPLE clauses. So pass in multiple clauses to a single call of `where`!!

Comment: That solved it! Thanks a lot Sir @DN1 ps:I overlooked that multiple clauses comment, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CriteriaQuery call to be

```
query.select(root)
    .where(builder.equal(root.get("dealerId"), dealerId), 
           builder.between(root.get("billDate"), frDate, tDate))
    .orderBy(builder.asc(root.get("billNo")));
```

so both where clauses are processed together in one call.